How to update custom field for Salesforce commerce cloud Shipment
As an admin, I need to update custom fields for all orders for the shipment of Salesforce Commerce Cloud. Which is the API I can use for my usecase?

Let suppose you define your attribute in System objects under shipment object and assigned that attribute to some custom group. It will be start showing into the existing orders in to the BM.
There are 2 ways to update the custom attribute values:

Via code, you can set the value during checkout and this will be carried over to the order object once the order is created in salesforce commerce cloud.

Manually: You can open any order and click on shipment. Then go to attributes tab, you will be able to see the newly created attribute over there.


If you want to bulk update shipment attributes then you can create a job in the business manager. for that purpose you need to write a script to fetch existing orders
an example script is here:
var sfccOrders = OrderMgr.searchOrders(
            'creationDate >= {0} AND creationDate <= {1} AND status != {2} AND custom.orderExportedToOMS != {3} AND custom.orderExportedToOMS != {4}',
            'creationDate desc',
            considerOrdersFrom,
            dateTo,
            statusFailed,
            'true',
            'false'
        ).asList().toArray();
    //from every order you can grab the shipment object like this.
    //loop through the sfccOrders Array.
    var defaultShipment = order.getDefaultShipment();
    shipment.custom.abcAttribute = 'My custom value'

You can fetch shipment object and assign the value.
